# Where can I find good introductory material for creating IE plugins?

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins

I can't seem to find any good introductory material for IE plugin development. MSDN documentation is quite lacking if you ask me. And I can't seem to find a simple intro example for IE plugins anywhere. Anyone know of any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this

http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.394345.4

or this one to

http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/developing-addons.php